# How to fix in KnexJs the error destroy of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

In my Node application, I'm running a script to generate a DB that uses the KnexJs query builder and the PostgreSQL

- "node": "~14.17.6"
- "knex": "^0.95.15"
- "pg": "^8.7.1"

The error I'm getting

```
Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined
    at process.value (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/make-knex.js:91:26)
    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:169:15)
    at success (/app/node_modules/knex/bin/utils/cli-config-utils.js:76:11)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:236:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

The script I'm running is as follow

```
const conn = {
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
  charset: 'utf8',
};

const databaseName = process.env.POSTGRES_DB;

const knex = require('knex')({ client: 'pg', connection: conn });

knex
  .raw('CREATE DATABASE ??', databaseName)
  .then(() => console.info('Successfully created db: ' + databaseName))
  .catch((err) =>
    console.warn('Warning: Unable to create db. Probably already exists.', err)
  )
  .finally(() => knex.destroy())
  .then(() => {
    const connection2 = knex({
      client: 'pg',
      connection: { ...conn, database: databaseName },
    });
    return connection2
      .raw('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext')
      .then(() => console.info('Successfully created extension citext'))
      .catch((err) => console.error('Unable to create extension citext.', err))
      .finally(() => connection2.destroy());
  })
  .then(() => process.exit(0));
```

I'm unable to understand what causes the issue and why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue probably is due to misunderstanding about what is the knex instance and what is the connection instance.

In this part:

```js
const knex = require('knex')({ client: 'pg', connection: conn });
```

You defined a **connection** using the knex module. So, when you invoke "knex" to create a second connection below:

```js
 .then(() => {
    const connection2 = knex({
      client: 'pg',
      connection: { ...conn, database: databaseName },
    });
```

`connection2` is not a connection because `knex` in this context **is the desired connection**. You could use the previously `knex` connection object.

To avoid these issues, I recommend you to separate things and rename variables to make it more explainable:

```
const knex = require('knex') // this is the knex module

const connection = knex({ client: 'pg', connection: conn }) // This is a connection using knex

// So you should use `connection` instead `knex`, as you are using the connection instance to perform queries

connection
  .raw('CREATE DATABASE ??', databaseName)

// ...

.then(() => {
    // Now this should work and return a connection
    const connection2 = knex({
      client: 'pg',
      connection: { ...conn, database: databaseName },
    });

    // But as connection2 is actually the same of connection, it could be
    // const connection2 = connection;
    return connection2 // or return connection
      .raw('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext')
      .then(() => console.info('Successfully created extension citext'))
      .catch((err) => console.error('Unable to create extension citext.', err))
      .finally(() => connection2.destroy());
  })
```

Another point to talk about is that if is really necessary to ends the connection and to create another one just after first `destroy()` call. As you can have an instance to the `connection`, so you can use it while you are performing queries and just destroy it once if it is not necessary anymore.